# Order of static variable declaration

Tags: c#

I have this this two codes:

```
private static int a = 5;
private static int b = a;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

And

```
private static int b = a;
private static int a = 5;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

Please explain to me why in the first case output is 5, but in the second one output is 0

Comment: The declarations happen first and then the initialization.

Comment: @WiktorZychla oh,yes, thank you. I was looking for something like that but didn't find.Shall I delete the question or somebody will just close it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the second case compiler will generate the following static constructor for type:

```
static Program()
{
   // Note: this type is marked as 'beforefieldinit'.
   Program.b = Program.a;
   Program.a = 5;
}
```

So, `a` equals `0` when it assign to `b`. Then `a` set to `5`